# Ubuntu Dual Boot second Linux Distro

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I have had some trouble dual booting Ubuntu 14 with another linux distro. 
I have an existing Ubuntu installiation running (nothing else besides Ubuntu 14, however), and the second .iso on a live usb.  When I reboot my computer with the live usb plugged in, I boot to my installed OS (ubuntu) rather than the usb.  I feel stupid, but have no idea how to boot from the usb.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to load the boot menu of the BIOS to change the boot priority.

While the computer is rebooting, hold down the key that gets you into the BIOS menu.  On my computers, it is either F12 or F7, but it may be different for your machine (it should say which button to press on the screen as the BIOS is loading).

Once you're in the BIOS menu, find the boot priority menu, and change the order such that the USB come before the HDD (you can always change this back later).

Also it occurs to me that maybe you haven't made the USB bootable?  What process did you go through in adding the iso image to the USB?

Comment: Many modern BIOS offer a boot medium selection menu so that you don't need to reconfigure the boot order for a one time boot off a removable medium. Search the BIOS POST screen for the right key combination (press the Pause key to stall it, any other key to resume) or consult the manual of your computer or mainboard.